# Open TCP Socket with Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sockets, tcp

How to create a TCP socket using Objective-C, check if some TCP ports are opened on the server?

I tried using some tutorials but none worked, because I need to create a server using an IP (198.168.0.000) and not a site, such as paypal.com, as some blog posts use.

I'm a little confused about which class to use and how to use. I know that is not the best place to ask, but do not know where to search.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/) for this kind of work. You can do it by hand, but if you're working in ObjC, then CocoaAsyncSocket is a much nicer interface.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look at [NSStream](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nsstream&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=jWd3T-O5J8fStAae_d20BA&usg=AFQjCNEdH2uZMUDxu0T3y15KuY756pcwNA&sig2=ZT2d6Up_y_jPq57ZT8eIPg) and its subclasses NSInputStream and NSOutputStream.

To check for connectivity you may also consider to take a look at [Reachability](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=reachability&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html&ei=0Gd3T5WtB8btsgaRg9G0BA&usg=AFQjCNGJ12F2PKta3FycNmMOiLv-MFfR7w&sig2=3t4RZgyfCxI8wBJJWUzg6w).

Besides Objective-C is a superset of C, so you can always rely on C structs/functions to create sockets ([Beej's guide to network programming](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=beej%20guide&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/&ei=9md3T4aKM47Tsgbez4y7BA&usg=AFQjCNH4AtfliDezGKzwmYTHYnzQafqzMw&sig2=7e7rlnQSJLqGol28PP1ChA))

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Apple's documentation is often a good idea. Read [Setting Up Socket Streams](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI) in *Stream Programming Guide*. With that under your belt, even if you decide to go with a third party library you'll have a pretty good idea of what it's doing under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few API choices on iOS for network sockets. If you have code to an existing BSD socket unix server that does what you want, I would create a secondary thread and just use the existing code on that thread. The best instructions for using BSD sockets is [Unix Network Programming by Stevens](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html).

If it's new code that runs on iOS only, I agree with Rob Napier that CocoaAsyncSocket is a reasonable way to go.