# Communicate with a running OS X application using perl

Tags: objective-c, macos, perl, cocoa, ipc

I need to use a perl script to communicate with a running OS X app (that I am developing).  The app doesn't need to communicate back to the script.  What are some simple / clean ways to do this?

Comment: This question requires opinion to answer, as there are many options available. Opinion questions are problematic at stack overflow, not the least reason of which: to express an opinion it needs to have some reasonable basis, and the description you've given leaves no foundation for such a basis.

Comment: @mah updated question to clarify.

Comment: How frequent is this communication, and what's the payload like size-wise?

Comment: @JoshCaswell quite small.  The purpose is to feed it paths of files to process.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few possible solutions:

- Perl opens up [ZMQ](http://search.cpan.org/~dmaki/ZMQ-1.05/lib/ZMQ.pm) socket and the OS X app uses the [objective-c bindings](http://zeromq.org/bindings:objc) to read that queue
- Writing Perl XS that can interact with [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-2831) provided by apple(also see [this SO discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842737/cocoa-notification-example)). There seems to be a replica of NSNotificationCenter [written in Perl here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Notification::Center).
- OSX seems to come with a Perl<==>ObjC bridge which [you can find more about here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/PerlObjCBridge.3pm.html)
- Your ObjC app listens on a socket and Perl connects and writes to it. See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959264/open-tcp-socket-with-objective-c) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html)
- Use pipes [as described here](http://www.macdevcenter.com/lpt/a/2954)
- Use unix sockets for IPC between Perl and Objc (see [this for objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858035/daemon-client-ipc-with-unix-sockets) and [this for Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) )
- Use UNIX Message queues([described here in Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html))
- Write [Perl XS bindings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) for [libdispatch](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/) (aka [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch)) or use [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline/C/C.pod) in Perl to access the libdispatch API